# Retrieving values from two tables from my Access DB and subtracting/output the result in C#

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, visual-studio-2012

Just beforehand, I am quite new to Visual Studio and C# so sorry if the question sounds somewhat stupid.

So i lately created an Access Database with a few tables. One of the tables is revenues (income) and one is expenses. Both these tables have one column with total income (income table) and total expenses (expense table) everything is added together in these columns.

These values can be adjusted and viewed in a front end windows form that i have created with C#.

Also the 2 total values of income and expense can be viewed. This is being done as follow (left the connection code, etc. out of this example):

```
try
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            string query = "select * from Income where Month='Januari'";
            command.CommandText = query;
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();   

            while (reader.Read())
            {

                total_income.Text = reader["Total income"].ToString();

            }                

            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
        }

try
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            string query2 = "select * from Expenses where Month='Januari'";

            command.CommandText = query2;
            OleDbDataReader reader2 = command.ExecuteReader();  
            while (reader2.Read())
            {

                total_expenses.Text = reader2["Total expenses"].ToString();

            }

            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
        }
```

So the total income and expenses are being outputted into a label.

The thing i want to achieve is subtracting the total income and total expenses in C# and outputting that result into a label or something (so i can view it in the form).

I try'd multiple things to achieve it, for example i try'd to store the  total_income.Text = reader["Total income"]; into a int variable and the same with total_expenses.Text but this cannot be done outside the try blocks (and since i have 2 for both expenses and income) this seems not to be possible. Also try'd some things with Convert.ToInt32(THE VAR) but this also didn't seem to work..

Is there a easy way to get these 2 different table values from the database and then subtract them in C# with the code and outputting it in a label? The 2 values have by the way a currency type in the Access database.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Variables could be declared also outside the try block, used inside the block and after existing the last block.

Comment: You could put both commands in separate methods with the desired return type (double?) and return the value from each query. You can then use them for whatever your pleasure is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare two decimal variables before the try/catch block, use them inside the block and do the math outsid of the blocks

If the two fields are not integers then you should use the appropriate data type (decimal) to handle currency values and use the appropriate convert method (Convert.ToDecimal) to set these local variables

```
decimal incomeSum = 0m;
decimal expenseSum = 0m;
try
{
    .....
    while (reader.Read())
    {

        incomeSum = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["Total income"]);
        total_income.Text = income.ToString();
    }                

    ....
    while (reader2.Read())
    {
        expenseSum = Convert.ToDecimal(reader2["Total expenses"]);
        total_expenses.Text = expenseSum.ToString();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
}
balance.Text = (incomeSum - expenseSum).ToString();
```

By the way, unless there is a reason not explained then you don't need to have two separate try catch blocks

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you. And no there is no specific reason for the two try blocks, just started in C# programming and still have to find out how to wright everything efficient. Though, wanted to give the functionality a priority;)

Comment: @Nicolas just to understand better your situation. The tables contain one row for month of there are more than one row for a single month? In the latter case the total income/expenses in the last row is already the sum of the previous rows or do you need to sum all the rows of a particular month to get your totals?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, I don't think your code is doing what you want. Iterating over the reader will overwrite the "total_" label with the current row. The Label will end up showing the value of the last row in your result set. I think you want to sum the values like:

```
  string incomeQry = "SELECT SUM([Total income]) FROM [Income] WHERE [Month] = 'Januari';";
  decimal totalIncome = 0m;

  try
  {
    using (OleDbConnection cnxn = new OleDbConnection("connection string..."))
    {
      using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(incomeQry, cnxn))
      {
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        totalIncome = (Decimal)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        total_income.Text = totalIncome.ToString();
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {        
    throw;
  }
```